# Curl of a magnetic field outside a wire = 0 even though it decreases with radius

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Outside an infinite length wire of radius a with even current distribution, the magnetic field vector for such a field would be

\begin{cases}  
      \frac{\mu_0Ir}{2\pi a^2} \hat{\theta} & r\leq a \\
      \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r} \hat{\theta} & r\gt a 
   \end{cases}
Mathematically, this would mean that the curl would be 0 everywhere outside the wire.

With my limited understanding of curl, I thought that as the strength of the field decreases with distance, that would mean that the varying strength would result in a net curl that would form at some point outside the wire.

Why would that not be the case?

Comment: This result shows that the strength of the magnetic field inside the wire is proportional to $r$ and outside the wire it is proportional to $1/r$. which means that the strength of the magnetic field drops as you move further away from the outside of the wire. Are you asking what would happen if the electric field in the wire is changing?

Comment: @Drjh As the magnetic field decreases, I'm asking the decreasing strength would, at least from what I think cause a net curl by difference in flow strength